# How can I fix the compling error on oneAPI code

Tags: c++, intel-oneapi

I am trying oneAPI from Intel office website: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/oneapi-programming-guide/top/programming-interface/example-compilation.html

I have completed step 1 “oneAPI Development Environment Setup” and verified it successfully.

In step 2, when I run `dpcpp -I${MKLROOT}/include -c axpy.cpp -o axpy.o`, it reports several errors:

`oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/bit_cast.hpp:33:22: error: no member named 'is_trivially_copyable' in namespace 'std'`

`oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/sycl_span.hpp:164:42: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'detail::remove_cv_t'`

`oneapi/compiler/2022.0.1/linux/bin-llvm/../include/sycl/CL/sycl/sycl_span.hpp:187:39: error: no template named 'is_array_v' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'is_array'`

I guess there is some compatibility issue, but I have no idea how to fix.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with the version of GCC that you have in your system, please check in the system requirements for DPCPP compiler from the below link, intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/… "Supported minimum versions of distributed libraries that the compilers are built on: GCC - 7.3.0, BINUTILS- 2.30, GLIBC-2.27"

Comment: Thanks, Vidyalatha. I run "oneapi/sys_check.sh", which prompts "the gcc version found on your path is not 7.4.0...you can point the compiler to that location with the --gcc-toolchain flag". the flag --gcc-toolchain does help me fix this issue.